# Flutter categories list base on another list of data

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two lists and need to get the category of each word and display it as a group.
my first list is where data is coming from.

```
final WordsList = [
  {
    'category': 'category-1',
    'words': ['Happy', 'Excited', 'Playful', 'Content', 'Grateful', 'Inspired']
  },
  {
    'category': 'category-2',
    'words': ['Confused', 'Doubtful','Confused']
  },
  {
    'category': 'category-3',
    'words': ['Scared','Horrified']
  },
```

Then the second list is from the user selection

```
List userSelection = [Happy, Confused, Doubtful, Scared, Horrified];
```

What i want to achieve is below.

| Category-1 | Category-2 | Category-3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Happy | Confused | Scared |
|  | Doubtful | Horrified |

Here is my code so far what I did was iterate the userSelection list and search the words from the word list and was able to retrieve the list but cannot figure out how to display it properly.

```
void getCategory() {
    var wordsDisplay = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < userSelection.length; i++) {
      wordsDisplay.add(WordsList
          .where((element) => (element["words"].contains(userSelection[i]))));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```dart
void main() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> wordsList = [
    {
      'category': 'category-1',
      'words': [
        'Happy',
        'Excited',
        'Playful',
        'Content',
        'Grateful',
        'Inspired'
      ]
    },
    {
      'category': 'category-2',
      'words': ['Confused', 'Doubtful', 'Confused']
    },
    {
      'category': 'category-3',
      'words': ['Scared', 'Horrified']
    },
  ];

  // using a set to eliminate duplicates like 'Confused' in category-2
  Set<String> userSelection = {
    'Happy',
    'Confused',
    'Doubtful',
    'Scared',
    'Horrified',
  };

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> wordsDisplay = [
    for (final category in wordsList)
      {
        // copy category into a new map
        ...category,
        // overwrite the 'words' key/value pair
        // the items we want are the set intersection of the userSelection
        // and the original words list.
        'words': userSelection.intersection({...?category['words']}),
      },
  ];

  print(wordsDisplay);
}
```

Comment: This approach did it, the next step is not display category that has empty words, thanks!

Comment: Should just be a matter of adding an `if` statement after the `for` statement with the right condition. I'll leave it to you to do the rest.